# Need help in migrating Hapi application to v20.0.1 from v16.4.3

Tags: node.js, migration, hapi.js, redundancy

`I need to migrate a hapi.js application from v16.4.3 to ^20.0.1.
Since there are major changes made in v17.0.0 including reply() interface upgradation. Is there any optimal way to replace

```
return reply()
```

to

```
return reply.reponse()
```

in all the handlers?

Node version: v16.20.2
Hapi version: v20.0.1

```
//working code with version v16.4.3(Hapi)

const addFoo = {
  description: 'add foo data',
  notes: 'add foo data',
  tags: ['api', 'FooCondition'],
  validate: {
    payload: {
      id: joi.number().required(),
    },
  },
  handler: (req, reply) => {
    return maindb.subcategorymaster.findAll({
where: {'id': req.payload.id}
}).then((result) => {
      reply(result);
    }).catch((DBException) => {
      reply(DBException.message);
    });
  }
};

// Wanted to migrate to below code without making manual change at each and every handler.

//working code with version v20.0.1(Hapi)

const addFoo = {
  description: 'add foo data',
  notes: 'add foo data',
  tags: ['api', 'FooCondition'],
  validate: {
    payload: {
      id: joi.number().required(),
    },
  },
  handler: (req, reply) => {
    return maindb.subcategorymaster.findAll({
where: {'id': req.payload.id}
}).then((result) => {
      return reply.response(result);
    }).catch((DBException) => {
      return reply.response(DBException.message);
    });
  }
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I tried using middlewares/lifecycle methods but didn't find a way to automate these changes. I also raised this issue at hapi github repo and got the answer as "**there isn't an automated or quick way to move from v16 API to v17+ API as the move to async/await kind of impacted the way you write your handlers.**" Please refer the [issue](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4480).

Currently we are planning to do manual changes in all the handlers.

You can also refer the v17.0.0 release notes [here](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/3658)